# Ionic View App with iOS device where data has not been shown

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-view

I have developed a small Ionic2 app.It is working fine on both locally on the web browser and "Ionic view" app's Android device.But the problem is on the Ios device.It shows UI correctly but no data.I have tested this on Ionic app viewer on Ios mobile device.Can you tell me why this strange behavior. I'm using Php as a web API layer (or back end).Can you tell me where is the issue is? If you need any info please let me know.At this moment I don't know what to provide here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OP's feedback**

Actually, the issue was `Date format`. We have to use ISO date format with the safari.

**OLD**

I guess that the problem is because the request is using SSL (https), with the request without SSL (http) should be work.

Source: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/solved-ionicview-app-http-request-to-external-api/18696

Comment: is this problem on Ionic view only? Will it work if I put the app on Apple store?

Comment: Try to test your App on iOS Simulator

Comment: sure,I'll do that.If it will work there then hope no problem on apple store also no?

Comment: After on debug on a real device, you can make sure that works fine.